# execution policy error while calling powershell script from batch file, powershell v 1.0

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have created a PowerShell script to get files from a subfolder. This executes when I run from the PowerShell console after manually entering `Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted`, but when I call the same script from a batch file

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe D:\programs\abc\bin\xyz_clean.ps1
```

it throws an error:

> xyz_clean.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system.

Comment: What OS are you running (including 32 vs. 64 bit)?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the execution policy in your batch? `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -file D:\programs\abc\bin\xyz_clean.ps1`  
Aside from that, there may be an issue between your "per user" and "machine" execution policies, you can try playing with the `-scope` parameter of set-executionpolicy

Comment: you missing the -file option. Are powershell scripts denied by  group policy?

Comment: Also, are you sure you're running PowerShell v1? The path to the executable is not proof of that, given that it hasn't changed in PS2 and PS3. Try checking the `PSVersion` attribute of the `$psversiontable` variable.

Comment: thnx for the reply my batch file looks like

Comment: when i look at the version foll is the output 'PSVersion 2.0'

Comment: @JamesWoolfenden- the ps scripts are not disabled by group policy. I can run it on another server. If i open a PS console and set-execution policy and then close this and run the batch file from cmd it works. But this is manual work

Comment: @Poorkenny- This 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -file D:\programs\abc\bin\xyz_clean.ps1' has worked for me perfectly.. Thanks to all of you guys!!!

Comment: @Poorkenny your suggestion worked for me, are you able to link me to why the batch script requires the policy inline, even if the same policy level is already set at the CurrentUser,LocalMachine, and Process(The non-group policy assignments) level in Powershell?

Answer (score 2):

You can just call powershell from a command window:

```
C:\> powershell /?
C:\> powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -file \\server\file.ps1
```

then save it to a .bat file:

```
C:\> echo powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -file \\server\file.ps1 > file.bat
```